# How to list all the database's tables in datagridview in winforms, and attach a checkbox to each table to carry out re-indexing of selected table?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I am very new to C# and trying to develop a tool to re-index selected tables of a sql server database so the user don't have to go into database and run any commands.

```
namespace DBTool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public DataSet GetTableNames()
        {
            try
            {

                //Local variables
                DataSet resultSet = new DataSet();

                //Get the connection string from the config file
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBTool.Properties.Settings.ConStr"].ConnectionString;

                //Create a new database connection
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                //Set the stored procedure 'sproc_Get_Tables_Names' as the command to be executed
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sproc_Get_Tables_Names", connection))
                {

                    //Setup the command object
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

                    //Open the connection
                    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                    }

                    //Execute the query and fill out the dataset
                    adapter.Fill(resultSet);

                    //Close the connection
                    connection.Close();

                    //Return the result of the stored procedure
                    return resultSet;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

               MessageBox.Show("An error occurred due to the following exception: " + ex.ToString() + ".","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
               return null;

            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet set = GetTableNames();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = set.Tables[0];
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part is holding you up? Getting the schema data? Binding the data to a DataGridView? Handling the checkbox event? The re-index sql statement? As your question stands I don't think anyone is going to give you all of this in one answer

Comment: Can't get to list the DB tables into datagridview... any help would be much appreciated... thanks.

Comment: @user2246352 - Given what you are asking, I _strongly_ suggest that you post what code you have written thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code against one of my databases (with a different stored proc) and it works. Are you getting *any* exception? Try setting timeout on the connection string to something low and running again.

The fact that the code works implies that SQL Server/Network Connectivity/Permissions are an issue, and the timeout is so long that you never get an exception back.

Some things to try:

- Does the stored proc execute ok on the server?
- If so, how much data is it returning? Are you returning a ridiculous
  amount of data and it's taking an age?
- Does the user supplied by the connection string have permissions to
  execute the stored proc?
- Can you make a connection to the SQL Server using SQL Management
  Studio using the same credentials?

Comment: Thank you Gareth, I got above code working too. The stored proc is also working and its returning all the tables as its supposed to. also the connection string is in config file and user do not provide it and yes i can connect to sql server using the management studio with same credential.

Now, how do i auto load the tables without click of the button. I know the code is under button click but i dont know where to put for it to auto load once i run the program.

Comment: You can put it in the form1_load event, since that gets called automatically when the form loads - but as that runs on the UI thread it will seize the UI if it's taking a long time to return data. Anyhow, it'd be good practice to spawn a separate thread for fetching data, you could use the Task Library or a BackgroundWorker process in order to keep the UI responsive.